# How to get data from TXT file?

Tags: powershell

I am working with **HP Operations Orchestration** and I am making a flow, which should read TXT file (which contain HTML source code) and getting information from it. What I want get, is data between `<h2></h2>` tags.

Unfortunately, when I start my flow, operation-component "Read from file" start infinity loop and work without stop.

Maybe somebody work with that program and know what I can do to get that data which I want? If you need more details, please write it in comments.

Some informations:

- I've got source code with using PowerShell script
- I don't use any JavaScript scripts (but I can add them)

Comment: A vague overview of a workflow doesn't contain nearly enough data for debugging. Nor is there a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$data >> "$env:USERPROFILE/sc.txt"
$result     =       Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE/sc.txt" | foreach { if ($_ -match "<h2>(.*?)</h2>"){  $matches[1]}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me an empty file.

Comment: I corrected one error, but now I've got whole source code in both files. But I'm still working.

Comment: Fixed the regex part too, this should help more.

Answer (score 0):

@Micky Balladelli

Here is my PowerShell code:

```
Clear-Host

# Create TXT file that containing source code
If (Test-Path "$env:USERPROFILE/sc.txt")
{
 Remove-Item "$env:USERPROFILE/sc.txt"
}
New-Item -name "sc.txt" -path "$env:USERPROFILE" -type file

If (Test-Path "$env:USERPROFILE/titles.txt")
{
 Remove-Item "$env:USERPROFILE/titles.txt"
}
New-Item -name "titles.txt" -path "$env:USERPROFILE" -type file

# Create an Internet Explorer com object
$URL        =       "geekweek.pl"
$wc         =       New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$ie         =       New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible =       $true
$ie.navigate($URL)
while ($ie.busy)
{
 start-sleep -second 10
}

$doc        =       $ie.Document
$data       =       $wc.DownloadString("http://www.geekweek.pl")

$data >> "$env:USERPROFILE/sc.txt"

$result     =       Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE/sc.txt" | foreach { $_ -split "<h2>(.*?)</h2>" -join ''}

$result >> "$env:USERPROFILE/titles.txt"

$ie.Quit()
```

Where:

- sc.txt - contain source code of "geekweek.pl"
- titles.txt - file where want save data from `<h2></h2>`

Actually I've got whole code in titles.txt